# MVC3 Razor - Response.WriteSubstitution always displays my text ontop of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

.
Dear Dev Guys :)

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC3 and I'm stuck when I use Response.WriteSubsitution() method.

Every time I try to use it in the page, the substitued text always appears on top of the page ([screenshot here](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9336/capturebkp.png)).

Considering I have the following code in my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }

        [OutputCache(Duration=20)]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now;
            return View();
        }
}
```

Code in About.cshtml :

```
@using MvcApplication1;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
    Date : @ViewBag.Date<br />
    Random Substitued number : @{ Response.WriteSubstitution(MvcApplication1.Helpers.Test); }
</p>
```

My Helper class:

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static string Test(HttpContext context)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            return r.Next(0, 10).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss something ?

Thanks !

**EDIT with solution:**

I solve the issue with the @Darin Dimitrov's solution.

For people in the same case of me, this is my new code.

My controller:

```
[DonutOutputCache(Duration = 10)]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now;
            return View();
        }

        public string RandomNumber()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            return r.Next(0, 10).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
```

MvcDonutCaching implements the class DonutOutputCacheAttribute we have to use instead the build-in OutputCacheOutput.

My View :

```
@using MvcApplication1;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Mobile/Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
    Date : @ViewBag.Date<br />
    Random Substitued number : @Html.Action("RandomNumber", true)
    @Side
</p>
```

The package overloads Html.Action method to control the cache :)

Thanks all people that feed this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm learning ASP.NET MVC3 and I'm stuck when I use Response.WriteSubsitution() method.

Forget about this method in ASP.NET MVC 3 as [Phil Haack explains](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx). Simply don't use it. If you wanna achieve donut caching in ASP.NET MVC 3, the framework has **nothing** to offer you.

There are [third party packages](http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/) that could enable this functionality if you don't want to roll your own.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ! The package MvcDonutCaching has solved my issue.

Comment: "the framework has **nothing** to offer you." Does this still apply for MVC 5? Should I stop banging my head against the wall trying to fix this?