# ASP.NET MVC - Display request processing time on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, profiling

I'd like to measure the time required to process requests in my ASP.NET MVC application and display this time on all the pages that my application generates. I wouldn't like to do the measurements in my controllers because I want to measure all the time that took ASP.NET to process each request including custom HTTP modules, any code in `Application_BeginRequest`, etc.

I've seen people do this using a separate HTTP module that makes use of `OnBeginRequest` and `OnEndRequest` event handlers:

```
void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    HttpContext.Current.Items["Stopwatch"] = stopwatch;
    stopwatch.Start();
}

void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stopwatch = (Stopwatch)HttpContext.Current.Items["Stopwatch"];
    stopwatch.Stop();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"{stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:0.000} sec");
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that I end up with invalid `HTML` markup. This logger appends all the text to the end of the response (after the closing `html` tag), but I want the response to be a valid `HTML` that contains profiling info somwhere inside the `body` tag.

Is there a way to do a (more or less) precise measurement of time elapsed between `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` and somehow inject the result properly into the generated HTML pages?

Comment: Check [HttpResponse.WriteSubstitution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writesubstitution(v=vs.90).aspx) also considering [MVC3 Razor - Response.WriteSubstitution always displays my text ontop of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11249345/1207195).

Comment: Take a look to [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) for this kinds of diagnostics

Comment: Second Glimpse. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I do know about Glimpse, but I only need to show this one number on my page, and I want to style it with CSS according to my site design (I need to show it to my end users). I don't need any other profiling info that Glimpse provides.